# How to quicly set up postfix to accept all messages coming to its domains (even if there is no corresponding user mailbox for the recipient address)?

Tags: linux, email, postfix

For example if I've got john.smith@example.com and ty.coon@example.com mailboxes set up, but someone sends  message to thomas.anderson@example.com I need the message to be stored to a special mailbox and reported (to the sender) as delivered instead of being returned with user-unknown error and discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix supports the use of a catchall account using the luser_relay configuration option.

See http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#luser_relay for more information.

"When the local(8) delivery agent finds that a message recipient does not exist, the message is normally returned to the sender ("user unknown"). Sometimes it is desirable to forward mail for non-existing recipients to another machine. For this purpose you can specify an alternative destination with the luser_relay configuration parameter."

Answer (score 1):

Just create a catch-all for your local domain as described in http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#luser_relay